# Creating a platform to handle CRUD scenarios for unknown entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create a platform that can read an XML or JSON configuration of entity names, their properties, and relationships and do basic CRUD operations on these entities as a starting point.

This means there will be no C# class definitions for these entities.

I would like to use a SQL Server database for this, however I believe it would be much easier to use something like a Graph or NoSql database since there is no predefined structure to create an ERD.

I would also like to use C#, Entity Framework, and JSON.NET to work with these dynamic entities and process business logic on them.

**Another way of explaining it is the following:**

Through a UI I would like someone to be able to do the following:

Create an Entity called Book.
A Book has the following properties: Title, Description, Author (one-to-one relationship w/ Author)

Create an Entity called Author.
An Author has the following properties: FirstName, LastName

What is a platform like this called and can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: We don't give suggestions, how would one mark them as correct, they would be subjective, all of which are off topic for this site. You may want to read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnB I rephrased it so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is a platform like this called and can someone lead me in the right direction?

Those applications are called *Database Administration*. Some examples are SQL Management Studio and PHPMyAdmin.

> I want to create a platform that can read an XML or JSON configuration of entity names, their properties, and relationships and do basic CRUD operations on these entities as a starting point.

Why do you want to do it? We already have many application which has decades of developement efforts.

A quick search showed me a tutorial how to create one [using ADO.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12404/Universal-Database-Admin-for-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Serve). I haven't taken a closer look to it, but you can be sure, such an application is not as simple as following a tutorial.

> I would also like to use C#, Entity Framework, and JSON.NET to work with these dynamic entities and process business logic on them.

Remember: Entity Framework is an [ORM (Object-relational mapping tool)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It's job is to *high level* map between your existing database and your application. You do not want to map your application code to a database, you want to administrate that database.

Therefore, EF is the wrong tool for the job. I think ADO.NET is the best you can do. You want to create a low level database application, so you need to use a low level tool.

---

That said, probably you want to just create some user defined content types? Then we are talking about a CMS. Probably you find some ideas in the [Orchard Content Management System](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/tree/dev/src/Orchard/ContentManagement).